# Angular 2 app not working in android 4.4.2 default browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

My Angular 2 App shows ...Loading screen (pre bootstrap Loading screen) in 4.4.2 android default browser (but works well on chrome browser in the same version) for some unknown reason. Also It works properly on latest browsers.
Below are my project configurations :-
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.10.2
npm: 3.10.10
Is there any way that I can make it run in the above mentioned browser.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update :-**
As @Gunter suggested, I created a sample demo app with all the pollyfills installed and that loads properly. I made the same pollyfills installations in my project, still It doesn't load on that old browser.
Any help on how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Did you follow https://angular.io/guide/browser-support (added polyfills)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, sorry for the late reply, I have added a `<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>` from the above link in my index.html file, still issue persists.

Comment: Sorry, don't know.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the `shim.min.js` should make it work, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days of working, found the cause of the problem,
My project had a **reflect.js** ("../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js")
script included, which when removed, my app started working on 4.4.2 android default browser.